# APScheduler not waking up scheduled jobs, when IDE is closed

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I am new to APScheduler package. I have scheduled a background job in MySQL job store. The script is working fine without any problem. I have scheduled the job with an interval of 2 minutes. The job is getting executed as long my IDE (sypder) is on. Whenever I am closing my IDE, the job is not getting executed further.

I have also tried with the interval as seconds & hours but the issue is same.
Please help

Below is my code :

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(.........)

......

scheduler.add_job(performjob,
                 'interval',
                  #days=1,
                  minutes = 2,
                  id='Test_Job',
                  start_date='2018-04-26 00:00:00',
                  end_date='2099-01-01 00:00:00',
                  args=[ob1,ob2],
                  name = "First Job for testing")
scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR | EVENT_JOB_MISSED | EVENT_SCHEDULER_STARTED)

try:
    scheduler.start()    
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Comment: What does this have to do with your IDE? Does this happen if you run the script outside your IDE? Also, you seem to be using BackgroundScheduler, so what is keeping your process running after `start()` returns?

Comment: I have also tried from a terminal, it executes as long as the terminal is not closed. I have also checked in MySQL table there is an entry <job id, next run time, state> but it never gets executed anymore if I close the terminal. It seems somehow the main thread is getting killed (I am not sure though).

I don't know what Scheduler would be best in case here since I need to execute the job with a day interval, and it's not working. Any suggestion or help??

Comment: Um, so you're wondering why the application closes when you close the terminal where you're running it?

Comment: Yes, and what will be the solution for it.

Comment: It is completely normal for an application to close when the terminal is closed. You need to take very special measures for something to continue running in the background. This is called "daemonization".

Answer (score 1):

You need to start scheduler in a separate process. Put your start command in a bash file, name it as scheduler_start.sh

Then in terminal

```
scheduler_start.sh; < ctrl > Z; bg; disown -h %1
```

There are several other ways to run a command in background. Read [more](http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-run-commands-background-nohup-disown) about it.